# How to change the background color of the cell content?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wrote some code and it will change the background color of the cell but I just want to change the color of the cell content.

I tried to look for the correct code but I could not fix it with my code.

```
Sub cellColor()
    Dim colCount As Integer
    Dim count As Integer

    colCount = Selection.Tables(1).Columns.count
    col = 0

    If Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
        While col < colCount
            Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 114, 86)
            col = col + 1
        Wend
    Else
        Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End If
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Not easier instead of `.Shading' use `.Interior.ColorIndex` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Shading` of the range of the cell, not of the `Selection` range.

This should work:

```
Selection.Cells(1).Range.Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 114, 86)
```